Is hair tinsel haram it is colored threads (maybe it is made of plastic)tie with hair in the same hair length wearing them at home and parties haram?
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
A photo for hair tinsel
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/oJ2N69HA.jpg
